# Unity Throws Exception While Instantiating Inherited Objects

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am getting exception when unity trying to resolve my object . Below is my test code and I am getting this exception .

**The current type, XXXXXXX, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping**?

```
namespace TrainMe.Data
{
    public interface ITestUnity
    {
        void Hello();
    }

    public class TestUnity : ITestUnity
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IDerieve
    {

    }

    public abstract class Base
    {
        private ITestUnity _testUnity;

        protected Base(ITestUnity testUnity)
        {
            _testUnity = testUnity;
        }
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }

    public class Derieve : Base, IDerieve
    {
        public Derieve(ITestUnity testUnity)
            : base(testUnity)
        {
        }
    }

}

public class TestFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IDerieve, Derieve>();
           container.RegisterType<ITestUnity, TestUnity>();

        }
    }
```

in **.CS** file

```
private readonly IDerieve _testUnity;
public ActionService(IDerieve test)
        {
            _testUnity = test;
        }
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here . This is a WCF project and I am using the library described [here](https://unitywcf.codeplex.com/) in codeplex .

Comment: What object are you resolving? You didn't show this type `XXXXXXX` in your question and didn't show the code you use to resolve it, and neither did you include a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it on my own . This was a project reference error .